# Unable to resize images in LinearLayout and Weight property set

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, android-studio

I'm trying to resize the images and increase the icon size however I have added them to a LinearLayout and each 5 icons share the weight. They fit by themselves thus making it impossible for me to increase their icon size/height/width.

**A Snapshot:**

[image]

**Here's my XML:**

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="5">

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@null"
                android:src="@drawable/feed_blue" />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@null"
                android:src="@drawable/compass" />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@null"
                android:src="@drawable/circle_blue" />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@null"
                android:src="@drawable/heart_beat" />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@null"
                android:src="@drawable/user_icon_female" />

        </LinearLayout>
```

I need to increase/decrease the size of my icons as I wish but the Weight property is probably limiting that ability. How can I get that done folks?

Comment: ScaleType to centerInside and fix the size you want in the pngs. I think those icons should be 24dp in height and width. Check the material design metrics.

Comment: You need to increase size of only one imageButton or all in the same time?

Comment: Maybe all or maybe one, depending on different icons mate @burakKarasoy

Comment: @Earthling added an option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="5">

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@null"
                android:src="@drawable/feed_blue" />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@null"
                android:src="@drawable/compass" />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@null"
                android:src="@drawable/circle_blue" />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@null"
                android:src="@drawable/heart_beat" />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@null"
                android:src="@drawable/user_icon_female" />

        </LinearLayout>
```

In this situation they all have %20 percent of total width you can change width easily by changing weight. And also you can change width and height using padding property.

Answer (score 0):

For normal app you need images pack for all android resources like **mipmap-hdpi, mipmap-mdpi, mipmap-nodpi, mipmap-xhdpi, mipmap-xxhdpi, mipmap-xxxhdpi** and you should not change image size programmatically, if you have not image pack try to play vs  `android:scaleType` in all buttons for example `android:scaleType="centerCrop"`

Comment: Nothing besides the launcher icon should be placed in the mipmap folders.

Comment: you are wrong please read
https://programmium.wordpress.com/2014/03/20/mipmapping-for-drawables-in-android-4-3/

Comment: I'm not wrong :) the difference in detail is not visible to the user. Official documentation states that mipmaps are just for launcher icons, because some launchers require for example xxxhdpi res when the device's density is xxhdpi. If you are concerned about performance and memory, use SVGs instead.